# Q_PROPERTY not setting a value to what is given through model on qml

Tags: c++, sqlite, qt, qml

im trying to update a value in my model through qml so I can get the users friends but for some reason it doesn't work. When basically the same code works for a different part of the program.

i've already tried setting the value with engine

main.cpp:

```
    qmlRegisterType<sqlFriendsModel>("chat.friendsModel", 1, 0, "SqlFriendsModel");
```

friendsmodel.h

```
#include <QSqlQueryModel>

class sqlFriendsModel : public QSqlQueryModel
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QString sender READ getSender WRITE setSender NOTIFY friendsList)

public:
   sqlFriendsModel(QObject *parent = 0);
   Q_INVOKABLE void setSender(const QString& sender);
   QString getSender() const;

private:
   QString m_sender;

signals:
    void friendsList();
};
```

friendsmodel.cpp

```
QString sqlFriendsModel::getSender() const
{
    return m_sender;
}

Q_INVOKABLE void sqlFriendsModel::setSender(const QString &sender)
{
    if (sender == m_sender)
        return;

    m_sender = sender;

    emit friendsList();
}

sqlFriendsModel::sqlFriendsModel(QObject *parent) :
    QSqlQueryModel(parent)
{
    createFriendsTable();

    qDebug()<< "sender is: " << m_sender;

    QString friendString = QString::fromLatin1("SELECT * FROM Friends WHERE You IS '%1'").arg(m_sender);

    QSqlQuery qry;
    if(!qry.exec(friendString))
        qFatal("Friends SELECT query failed: %s", qPrintable(qry.lastError().text()));

    setQuery(qry);
    if (lastError().isValid())
        qFatal("Cannot set query on SqlContactModel: %s", qPrintable(lastError().text()));

}
```

mainwindow.qml

```
    import chat.friendsModel 1.0

    property string author

    model: SqlFriendsModel {
         sender: author
    }
```

login.qml

```
    root.StackView.view.push("qrc:/mainwindow.qml", { author: userTextField.text })
```

i have also tried running this on mainwindow.qml:

```
    Component.onCompleted: {
        _friendsModel.setSender(author)
    }
```

the actual value author acts like I want but whenever I try to set sender in friends model it remains empty

edit:

after messing around with breakpoints i found out that the sqlfriendsmodel loads first and only after that setSender() works and sets m_sender to desired value. now i just need to make it so setSender() runs first.

Comment: maybe cause you didn't define the core of `getSender()` in `friendsmodel.cpp`

Comment: @TomKim what exactly do you mean by core of getSender() ?

Comment: The code you post in your question `getSender()` is not defined on `friendsmodel.cpp`

Comment: You are using `setSender` with both `Q_PROPERTY` and `Q_INVOKABLE`. Is there any reason for that?

Comment: @user3405291 it stayed there when i tried using the component.oncompleted code from what i can see either way still doesn't work

Comment: In the constructor where you have the qDebug(), the value can’t be anything but empty, there was no chance for anyone to change the value yet.

Comment: Can you try this: ```Component.onCompleted: {
        _friendsModel.sender = author
    }```

Comment: At `getSender()` function, you have `return m_SENDER;`. Shouldn't it be `return m_sender;`?